# CLion configurate and test library project

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, clion

Let's say I wanted to develop a simple library with the following structure:

[image: project structure]

My CMakeLists.txt then looks like this:

```py
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(INC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/")
set(SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")

file(GLOB INCLUDES "${INC_DIR}/httplib/*.hpp")
file(GLOB SOURCES "${SRC_DIR}/*.cpp")

project(httplib)
add_library(httplib STATIC ${INCLUDES} ${SOURCES})
include_directories(${INC_DIR})
```

This works fine but what is the usual way to configure CLion projects and CMake in order to test a library effectively ?

Comment: There is no the best way for organize a project in CMake. You could create tests in the same `CMakeLists.txt` where you create the library. You could create tests in `CMakeLists.txt` located in the subdirectory, and include it via `add_subdirectory`. You may create separate test project. Many ways.